# Linq OrderBy Any Property

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, sql-order-by

I know how to order by one property, then another property. I'm wondering if there is a linq way to order by any property (or multiple properties at the same time).

For example a list of names:

```
   ->Adam     Jones
   ->Dude     Lebowski
   ->Zander   Berry
```

Would be sorted:

```
   ->Adam     Jones
     Zander ->Berry
   ->Dude     Lebowski
```

Comment: How is sorting by "multiple properties at the same time" different from sorting by one property and then by another?

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP wants to sort by the earliest-sorting value of two properties.

Comment: How do you sort `Adam Jones` and `Jones Adam`? in which order?

Comment: @LBushkin - the `ThenBy` only happens when there are multiple rows with the same value on the first OrderBy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an odd one to want.

You can pass any Func<TSource, TKey> you like into OrderBy:-

```
names.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName.CompareTo(x.LastName) < 0
                     ? x.FirstName
                     : x.LastName);
```

---

Or if you think the inline ternary looks ugly (or if you need to reuse the sort all over the place), you can write your own IComparer:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx

```
class PersonFirstOrLastNameComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
  public int Compare( Person x, Person y )
  {
    return GetKey( x ).CompareTo( GetKey( y ) );
  }

  private String GetKey( Person person )
  {
    if ( person.FirstName.CompareTo( person.LastName ) < 0 )
    {
      return person.FirstName;
    }
    else
    {
      return person.LastName;
    }
  }
}
```

and:-

```
names.OrderBy(x => x, new PersonFirstOrLastNameComparer());
```

---

Really though, I'd advise against it. If you find yourself sorting by the earlier of two properties on a model class, I suspect it's likely that your model class isn't up to the task.

I can't say more without knowing more about your specific application, but I'd probably advise either encapsulating that logic inside the model class (either by providing a specific property e.g. Person.SortKey or if it's a universal sort by overriding CompareTo) or creating a view model. The code snippets I posted would be a bit of an eyebrow-raiser in a code review. I think keeping the logic with the model (or ViewModel) would clarify the purpose.

Comment: Ah! that is pretty simple. I was thinking there would be a `.OrderBy((x, y) => /**/)` similar to a `sort` function but this does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
.OrderBy(obj => (obj.PropA < obj.PropB) ? obj.PropA : obj.PropB)
```